# Firefox 9 (Mac) is bugged parsing margins?

Tags: html, css, firefox, layout, margin

I've got very weird problem in my current project. The `#head` div looks like has `margin-top` css setting enabled, while it is not. It only occurs on Firefox 9.0.1 (Mac), other browsers are ok.

Here's [link to the demo layout](https://dev.makov.org/arscenique/index.html). Not sure if it happens in FF 9.0.1 Win version. However, IE7 renders it correctly. Refer to attached image to see how it renders. So, if you disable the `margin-bottom:23px` under the `#head` div in Firebug, you'l see it'll move up, but why the heck!? It was the `margin-BOTTOM` setting we've disabled...

Is this me, or is this FF?

[image: The problem in FF 9.0.1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that the bottom margin is collapsing with the top margin and the result is all being treated as top margin.  The CSS spec requires this behavior, and all modern browsers (which doesn't include IE7, of course) implement it.

Comment: Like I said, the problem was only in Firefox. Safari, Chrome, Opera (all latest versions) were fine rendering it. Besides, Firebug did not see that there was a `top-margin` computed. Could you provide a link to the part of the CSS reference that describes required behavior?

Comment: Collapsing affects used values, not computed values.  The relevant spec section is http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins fourth item of the third item of the "Two margins are adjoining" list.  Also same section, the text that says "If the element's margins are collapsed with its parent's top margin, the top border edge of the box is defined to be the same as the parent's."  That's the case you hit here.  Browsers all do this, in the simple testcase, I just tried, so I have no idea why on your particular page Opera and WebKit do something different.

Comment: Ah, looks like the .cf:after style is affecting the behavior in other browsers but not in Firefox for some reason.  I'll file a bug on Firefox just in case.

Comment: Ah, you may be running into https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=451791 .  Instead of adding something that will break when that bug is fixed, it's probably better to give your #head a very small (0.01px, say) bottom padding to prevent the margin collapsing behavior to start with.

Comment: Thanks Boris! Really appreciate your insightful replies!

Answer (score 0):

you could always put this inside your stylesheet.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #head{
        margin-top: -10px !important;
    }
}
```

check it - http://jsfiddle.net/nBWLq/2/.

Comment: Using UA-specific hacks to "work around" correct implementation of a spec will just mean it's broken in other UAs that happen to implement the spec, no?